# Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{4^{k}}=\frac{4}{3}-\frac{1}{3 \cdot 4^{n}}$ converges to $\frac{4}{3}$ using the $\varepsilon-N$ proof

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

For all $n \in \mathbb{N} \cup\{0\}$, $P(n)$ is defined as $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{4^{k}}=\frac{4}{3}-\frac{1}{3 \cdot 4^{n}}$.

After my first attempt, I thought that $N = \log _{4}(\frac{1}{3\varepsilon})$, which is incorrect. The answer is $N \geq-\log _{4}(\varepsilon)$. Does anyone know how to come up to this correct $N$? Appreciate any help!

Comment: Proofs like this often only bother with obtaining a sufficient, easy to write expression for $N$, rather than the tightest bound they can manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_n := \tfrac43 - \tfrac1{3 \cdot 4^n}$. Now, you want to show that $S_n \to \tfrac43$. Given $\varepsilon > 0$, you desire $|a_n - \tfrac43| \le \varepsilon$. But the left-hand side is precisely $1/(3 \cdot 4^n)$. So just choose the smallest $N$ such that $1/(3 \cdot 4^N) \le \varepsilon$, ie $N := \lceil \log_4(\tfrac1{3\varepsilon}) \rceil$, as you rightly noted.

Comment: Yes I came to the same conclusion but the answer is something different. Any idea where it is coming from?

Comment: If $N \ge \log_4(\tfrac1\varepsilon)$, then $N \ge \log_4(\tfrac1{3\varepsilon})$. You shouldn't get hung up on these sorts of things. The specifics aren't important :) -- important is your understanding that you're proving that $1/4^n \to 0$. Doesn't really matter if you use $\varepsilon$ or $3 \varepsilon$

Comment: Ok, would like to thank everyone for his/her help. Forgot to accept an answer yesterday, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think we could take a not so strange norm for $N$. As you well know, it all comes down to proving that $\frac{1}{3\cdot 4^n}\to 0$.

Let $\epsilon>0$, we can take $N=\left\lfloor\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}\right\rfloor+1>\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}$, then for $n>N$ we have
$$
\left|\frac{1}{3\cdot 4^n}\right|<\left|\frac{1}{3\cdot 4^N}\right|<\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon
$$
Thus $\frac{4}{3}-\frac{1}{3\cdot 4^n}\to \frac{4}{3}$ when $n\to \infty$.